# phpstorm как отключить слежение за каждым символом?

Tags: phpstorm

Очень бесит когда в шторме вводишь функции он сразу с первого символа подставляет имя функции, это конечно круто, но это иногда хорошо так подвисает, особенно на ноуте. Тормоза эти бесят. 
Я знаю там есть какой то безопасный экономичный режим. 
Но это я думаю через чур. 
Как отключить слежение, чтобы он мне подсказывал не с 1го символа, а хотябы с 3го

Comment: отключите автоматическое, вызывайте руками

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отключить **Show suggestions as you type** в **Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion** и вызывайте подсказку вручную, с помощью `Ctrl+space`.

P.S. в версиях < 2018.2.x эта опция называется **Auto-display code completion**